# Is modin useful on AWS Lambda

Tags: pandas, aws-lambda, modin

AWS Lambda comes with 6 vCPU. Modin for Pandas promises to use cores to make processing efficient.

Does this actually deliver on AWS Lambda, which otherwise does not support multi-threading, multi-processing etc. ?

```
# import pandas as pd
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-pandas/issues/2370

I think we cannot use modin on lambda because Modin requires some kind engine to work on distributed computing hence If someone wants to use modin on lambda then they may create their own container, with the engine they want to use along with it..

Alternatively the easiest way could be you can use something as

pip3 install awswrangler[modin,ray]
in your container directly